# Person recolonization using ML.NET/TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, ml.net

I am noob in ML. I have a Person table that have,

```
-----------------------------------
               User
-----------------------------------
UserId | UserName | UserPicturePath
1      |   MyName | MyName.jpeg
```

Now I have tens of millions of persons in my database. I wanna train my model to predict the `UserId` by giving images(png/jpeg/tiff) in bytes. So, input will be images and the output I am looking is `UserId`. Right now I am looking for a solution in ML.NET but I am open to switch to TensorFlow.

Comment: Does it need to be a custom solution? If not there's a face detect service on the Microsoft Cognitive Services

Comment: Have you done something similar? Will one image per record will able to predict?

Comment: do you mean if one image per record is enough to train the model? If yes, then  you need to augment your data (transform, shear, bend, etc) first so that you will generate more records per id. Ideally, you should have multiple images per id so that your model is robust. Regarding if I have done something similar, the answer is yes, and, actually the code I shared is very popular and many people have done this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is nothing but a mapping problem, particularly an id-to-face mapping problem, and neural nets excell at this more than on anything else.

As you have understood by now, you can do this using tensorflow, pytorch or any library of the same purpose.

But if you want to use tensorflow, read on for a ready code at the end. It is easiest to achieve your task by transfer learning, i.e. by loading some pretrained model, freezing all but last layer and then training the network to produce a latent one-dimensional vector for a given face image. Then you can save this vector into a database and map it into an id.

Then, whenever there is a new image and you want to predict an id for the image, you run your image through the network, get your vector and compute cosine similarity with vectors in your database. If the similarity is above some threshold and it is the highest among other similarities, you have found your id.

There are many ways to go about this. Sure you have to preprocess your data, and augment it at the same time, but if you want some ready code to play with then have a look at this famous happy house tutorial from Andrew NG and his team:

https://github.com/gemaatienza/Deep-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/4.%20Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/Keras%20-%20Tutorial%20-%20Happy%20House%20v2.ipynb

This should suffice your needs.

Hope it helps!